# How should I handle internationalisation in a React library of components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization

I could find a lot of examples of how to do internationalisation in a React application but I couldn't find any for a library of components.

I'm using phraseapp and I would like to know if someone has a suggestion of how to do it in a good way.

1. All components receive as props the language that should use
2. All translations are in phraseapp
3. It's a library of components for the company that I work, so this library will have default labels that need translations

Options that I thought:

- Load the key/values for the current language in the apollo client store and create a helper to get the value given a key
- Try to use a lib like this: https://github.com/phrase/react-intl-phraseapp but I don't know if is going to work because is not a SPA

Comment: Hi Marina, I'm in exactly the same situation now. Just considering to use react-intl on every component that we export where we'd call the common utility method loading the language and messages to be used... It's not too elegant solution, but might work. Did you get anywhere further with your solution?

Comment: Hi @Kuba, thanks for the replay, I'm going to try different solutions on the next week and I can share with you the best solution that I could find. Your solution is one of the options that I'll try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so we've finally ended up using `react-intl`, exporting each component wrapped inside the `IntlProvider` with whatever the locale and messages are just required. The config for IntlProvider is set in component's state inside a constructor:

```
    this.state = {
       i18nCfg: IntlUtils.init(props.language, 'SignOutMenu')
    }
```

... and then set in components' `render()`:

```
    render() {
      const { i18nCfg } = this.state;
      return (
         <IntlProvider locale={i18nCfg.language} messages={i18nCfg.messages}>

...
```

The locale can be supplied by parent component as given by `injectIntl` HOC

```
<SignOutMenu language={this.props.intl.locale}/>
```

or detected from browser with a util method `getUserLanguage()` on `init()` if no language is defined.

You just have to be careful to prevent duplicate occurrence of message id's in the app, so therefore I initialised the component with a namespace string representing the messages related only to that given component (done in `getMessages()`):

```
    import {addLocaleData} from 'react-intl';
    import en from 'react-intl/locale-data/en';
    import de from 'react-intl/locale-data/de';
    import messagesEn from '../locales/lang/i18n_en.json';
    import messagesDe from '../locales/lang/i18n_de.json';

    const defaultLanguage = 'en';
    const supportedLanguages = ['en', 'de'];

    export default class IntlUtils {

       static init = (language, namespace) => {
          // add the supported locale data
          addLocaleData([...en, ...de]);

          // get supported language
          const lang = language && supportedLanguages.indexOf(language) > -1 ? language : IntlUtils.getUserLanguage();

          // return back data for IntlProvider
          return {
             language: lang,
             messages: IntlUtils.getMessages(lang, namespace)
          }
       }

       static getMessages = (language, namespace) => {
          let langMsgs;
          switch (language) {
             case 'de': langMsgs = messagesDe; break;

             case 'en':
             default: langMsgs = messagesEn;
          }

          if (langMsgs) {
             const matchNS = namespace + ".";
             const filtered = {};
             for (var key in langMsgs) {
                if (key.startsWith(matchNS)) {
                   filtered[key] = langMsgs[key];
                }
             }
             return filtered;
          }
       }

       static getUserLanguage = () => {
          //if none available, take it from browser
          const browserLanguage = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
          if (browserLanguage) {
             // get the language code and store it in local prefs for nexttime
             const m = browserLanguage.match(/^([a-z]+)/i);
             if (m) {
                return m[0];
             }
          }
          // nothing found -> return default en
          return defaultLanguage;
       }
    }
```

To be able to import the json files in `IntlUtil`, I had to install devDependency of "babel-plugin-inline-json-import" and add it to .babelrc file:

```
   "plugins": [
      ["inline-json-import", {}]
   ]
```

Also I found using injectIntl HOC with method `formatMessage()` didn't work properly in the same component where IntlProvider was initialised as HOC used instance of the `IntlProvider` with messages from component above).

Note, that our language switching mechanism involved a refresh of the page, so it worked like a charm with `init()`. But I can't say how well it would work in case of using context or redux, when you're switching the language without page refresh. But we're going to use it in one such application soon, so I may post here the updates then...

Hope this helps you and others at least somehow

Comment: Thank you @Kuba for sharing your solution. Here we decided to share the ids/values translations via context. Basically, we created a TranslationsContext and for each component, you have to create a TranslationsContext.Consumer and to use the component you need to create TranslationsContext.Provider. It's not the best solution but is easy and fast to implement

Comment: Yup, that's also the way to do it... and as you say, it's easy and fast, which is good. Nice one :o) Thanks for info @Marina